# No "figcaption" available for the "picture" tag in HTML?

Tags: html, image

Must I select between **figure** (with inner **img** & **figcation**) and **picture** (with multiple **source** tags)? I want both **figcation** and multiple **source** tags per one parent tag.

### "figure" + "img" + "figcapiton" example

```
<figure>
  <img
    src="images/dinosaur.jpg"
    alt="The head and torso of a dinosaur skeleton;
            it has a large head with long sharp teeth"
    width="400"
    height="341" />

  <figcaption>
    A T-Rex on display in the Manchester University Museum.
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Images_in_HTML)

### "picture" + "source" + "img" example

```html
<picture>
  <source media="(max-width: 799px)" srcset="elva-480w-close-portrait.jpg" />
  <source media="(min-width: 800px)" srcset="elva-800w.jpg" />
  <img src="elva-800w.jpg" alt="Chris standing up holding his daughter Elva" />
</picture>
```

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images)

### What I want (currently the invalid HTML)

```html
<picture>

  <source media="(max-width: 799px)" srcset="elva-480w-close-portrait.jpg" />
  <source media="(min-width: 800px)" srcset="elva-800w.jpg" />
  <img src="elva-800w.jpg" alt="Chris standing up holding his daughter Elva" />

  <figcaption>
    Chris standing up holding his daughter Elva
  </figcaption>
</picture>
```

Comment: I think you can have a `<picture>` *inside* a `<figure>`

Comment: Not a fix but please note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) and  [<source>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tags do not use and do not need a closing slash and never have in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, you do something like:

```
<figure>
<img src="image.jpg" alt="The Image">
<figcaption>A Caption</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: Which the OP knows about (first sample)

Answer (score 0):

Just checked mr. Hans Keﬆing's assumption by HTML validator.
Fortunately, the `<picture>` inside a `<figure>` is the valid HTML (at least for the March 2023).

```html
<figure>
  <picture>
    <source media="(max-width: 799px)" srcset="elva-480w-close-portrait.jpg">
    <source media="(min-width: 800px)" srcset="elva-800w.jpg">
    <img src="elva-800w.jpg" alt="Chris standing up holding his daughter Elva">
  </picture>
  <figcaption> A T-Rex on display in the Manchester University Museum. </figcaption>
</figure>
```

[image]